# Does IBM Z/OS Connect EE allow authoring custom REST API

Tags: connect, zos, zos-connect-ee

In our current project , We have a need to run queries from Azure on z/os systems. We plan to use IBM Z/OS Connect EE for integration from Azure cloud to Z/OS. We found that Z/OS Connect EE provides out of box features, to construct API on z/os subsystems like IMS, DB2, CICS.. Can we also author custom REST API's that we can deploy to IBM Z/OS Connect EE?

Also , Does  IBM Z/OS Connect EE provide features to develop custom connectors to other mainframe systems?

Comment: [IBM z/OS Connect EE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS4SVW_3.0.0/com.ibm.zosconnect.doc/configuring/other_service_provider.html) provides the ability to connect to CICS, DB2, IMS, MQ, and any [WOLA-enabled](https://www-03.ibm.com/support/techdocs/atsmastr.nsf/WebIndex/WP101490) z/OS application in a RESTful manner.  What "other mainframe systems" do you wish to connect to?

Answer (score 2):

IBM z/OS Connect EE provides the capability for you to add your own custom service provider. The information on how to do such can be found in the knowledge center here:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS4SVW_3.0.0/com.ibm.zosconnect.doc/extending/create_srvc_provider.html